# Add text to an asp.net label before the bound label text

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I have seen it done before but i cannot remember where (vs2012 even):

```
<asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
```

Some tag I can add to the label (or textbox?)

So that when I bind "Hello World!" to the label, I can have the label output:  "Welcome, Hello World!"

My label would look like:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" Text="" PrependedText="Welcome, "></asp:Label>
```

Comment: My theory was that you can do it "inline" in the HTML so the designer has the ability to do this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several ways to go about this...

```
Welcome, <asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
```

or

```
<asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>

lblMessage.Text="Welcome, Hello World!";
```

or

```
public class MySpecialLabel: Label
{
public string PrependedText {get;set;}

//logic here to handle combining the strings when Text is set.
}
```

or

```
<div class="WelcomeSection">
  Welcome, <asp:Label runat="server" id="lblMessage">
</div>
```

Comment: 1st answer does not work, b/c the Welcome will show up even if the lblMessage is marked as visible=false, so it defeats my specific purpose/need.

Comment: 2nd answer also does not fulfill my needs, as the designer cannot edit the 'welcome' comment, nor can anyone change it without a recompilation. Ouch.

Comment: 3rd one looks a lot like what I need, but is incomplete, what should the //logic be? need help...

Comment: @ransems Why did you mark this as answer if it didn't answer your question? Why are you coming at this 2 years later?

Answer (score 1):

You can write your own control derived from Label or just put another before with text from resources or hardcoded:

```
<asp:Label ID="lblPrepend" runat="server" Text="Welcome, " />
<asp:Label ID="lblMessage" runat="server" Text="" />
```

Comment: This will probably be the best, not ideal but great.  Reason why, I am formatting the label(s) based upon logic from DB. And I want the design guys to be able to change the pre-pended text.  the second label data is also coming from the DB.